# Elasticsearch: how to sum the result of all buckets in one field?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch Version: 5.0
i tried to get the count of all buckets, but i don't know how get it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the [sum bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html)?

Comment: @Val i want to sum the doc_count of each buckets in "most_frequently_used_value" field.

Comment: Note that you can easily do it on the client-side, too.

Comment: As @Val suggested, you could use a `JSONArray` in order to retrieve the `total buckets` from the `hits` programmatically.

Comment: @Val i have solved it with define a variable for sum outside the loop. i think there have other config for aggs can replace my methods.  so i asked it at here. Kulasangar i have many fields in one aggs, so the total buckets from hits is not correct. thanks.